# Write a MS SQL Server Query when 2 tables have associated ID

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that was written by a developer who has stopped freelancing. I want to be able to query the data which is in 2 tables in a database.

To simplify this all I have a subset of the columns I want to query.

Table `Main` has details for races.

- **col_id** has the number for each unique race.
- **col_race** has the race name
- **col_course** is the track that a race was run at
- **col_dist** has the race distance

Table `Details` has the horses details for each race.

- **col_maind** is the col_id from the Main table
- **col_fpos** is the finishing position in the race
- **col_weight** is the weight carried (i.e.) 140
- **col_rating** is a figure awarded to the horse.

I would start the query with something like this but it is getting the information from both tabes to display in the result I cannot do.

```
 SELECT col_maind, col_fpos, col_weight

 WHERE col_rating >'150'
 ORDER BY col_rating DESC
```

The part I would appreciate help and advice is how can I display the associated information from the MAIN table.

Output would be displayed as

```
col_mainid.details, col_fpos.details, col_rating.details, col_race.main, col_course.main, col_dist.main
```

What is the easiest query to have the result display the information?

i.e. 4535555 2 155 "The test race handicap" Woodbine 1100

Regards …. Chris

Comment: The concept you need to know about is INNER JOIN.

Comment: use inner join with table prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple INNER JOIN should do it:

```
SELECT details.col_maind, 
       details.col_fpos, 
       details.col_rating, 
       main.col_race, 
       main.col_course, 
       main.col_dist
FROM main
INNER JOIN details on main.col_id = details.col_mainid
 WHERE details.col_rating >'150'
 ORDER BY detailscol_rating DESC
```

Comment: Thank you all of you for replying. I will look at using Inner Join in a query... Especially JMabee for presenting how, this should look as in a query.

Answer (score 1):

```
select td.col_race,
       td.col_course,
       tm.col_fpos,
       tm.col_weight  
from TableMain tm 
inner join TableDetails td on tm.col_id=td.col_maind
where td.col_rating >'150'
```

you can use Inner Join query for getting results from two tables

Comment: In the future I suggest you either add an order by clause (because it is almost always significant) or add a note about unordered resultsets. A note about the best practice of adding aliases for tables and using them consistently is also helpful.